# Java Swing: JScrollPane not working

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I have a JPanel which contains some fields. The height of the JPanel is limited so I have to put a JScrollPane around it so people can scroll down.

As you can see below, it displays perfectly. But you can't scroll down (or up).

```
DetailPanel detail = new DetailPanel();
JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(detail);
jsp.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
jsp.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
jsp.setBounds(745, 10, 235, 225);
add(jsp);
```

Detail panel:

```
private void init(){
            setLayout(null);
            setSize(140, 400);
            int x = 5, y = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < lbls.length; i++) {
                JLabel lbl = new JLabel(lbls[i]);
                lbl.setBounds(x, y, 200, 25);
                add(lbl);
                fields[i] = new JTextField();
                fields[i].setBounds(x, y+26, 200, 25);
                add(fields[i]);
                y+=50;
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your DetailPanel has no layout manager associated with it, which means it doesn't expand when you add children to it, which means the JScrollPane doesn't have anywhere to scroll.  Either call `setLayout()` on your DetailPanel or override `getPreferredSize()` to add up the heights of its children and return a meaningful value.

Comment: Future reference, as I couldn't get this thing right: trying to use the setter, i.e. `setPreferredSize()`, is WRONG, as orzechowskid says you need to override the getter, i.e. `getPreferredSize()`, this is very important.

Answer (score 3):

I could be wrong, but I think this might be happening because DetailPanel's layout is null.  What happens if you use a BoxLayout in vertical orientation and call `detail.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(140,400));`?

Comment: +1 for spotting the culprit -1 for setPrefSize (it's a no-no-never, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519)