# Java GUI JScrollPane

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jscrollpane

I am a beginer at programing and i wanted to add a scroll panel to a JTextArea so i tried to research tutorials online. i followed the examples but its not working can someone plz tell me what i am doing wrong. thank you so much

```
    public View(Model model) {
    this.model = model;
    setBounds(100,50, 800, 400);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Container c =  getContentPane();
    addDisplay(c);
    addButtons(c);
    addTxt(c);

}

private void addDisplay(Container c){
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    addTxt2(p);
    addTxt(p);
    add(p, "North");

}

    private void addTxt(JPanel p){
        txt = new JTextArea(15, 35);
        txt.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        txt.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        txt.setEditable(true);  

        JScrollPane scroll= new JScrollPane (txt);
        p.add(scroll); 


}
```

Comment: What you're doing wrong is not telling us what is wrong.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: its just not doing anything like the scroll part is not there

Comment: You have to put enough text in the text area to cause the scroll bar to appear.

Comment: i did but the txt area just becomes longer

Comment: Please paste the [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) for better help

Comment: What is the `layout` of your `p`?

Comment: I think the scrollpane just grows and grows. It depends on the LayoutManager you're using in the JPanel. Try to set a maximum Size scroll.setMaximumSize().

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10016879/java-swing-jscrollpane-not-working?rq=1

Comment: `add(p, "North")` - Don't hardcode the constraint. Use the constraints provided by the API - `BorderLayout.NORTH`.

Answer (score 1):

Always invoke `revalidate` and `repaint` after adding any components to a `JPanel`

```
p.add(scroll); 
p.revalidate();
p.repaint();
```

From the use of `setBounds`, it appears that there is no layout manager in use. Don't use absolute positioning (`null` layout). By default, components have a size of `0 x 0` so will not appear unless their size is set. A layout manager should be used here instead.

Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for better help sooner

Comment: i tried that but its still the same. the txt area is still just getting longer.

Comment: You're not using `null` layout by any chance? If so then components need to be sizes set explicitly. That's why its always better to use a layout manager

Comment: @user2410760 again repeating Please paste the SSCCE for better help, important is info if is added to already visible contianer or

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the bounds of your scroll `setBounds(int, int, int, int)`
and define the area of your `JTextArea`

Here's an example:

```
public class ScrollingTextArea extends JFrame {

    JTextArea txt = new JTextArea();
    JScrollPane scrolltxt = new JScrollPane(txt);

    public ScrollingTextArea() {

        setLayout(null);

        scrolltxt.setBounds(3, 3, 300, 200);
        add(scrolltxt);     
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ScrollingTextArea sta = new ScrollingTextArea();
        sta.setSize(313,233);
        sta.setTitle("Scrolling JTextArea with JScrollPane");
        sta.show();     
    }

}
```

I've found it [here](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-swing-tutorials/38-java-program-add-scroll-bars-jtextarea-using-jscrollpane.html)